# Protractor - pass value from one describe /IT block to another

Tags: protractor

I have two portals.one is admin and one is for end user. I create product in admin and create order in eu. 
I have created product in one describe block.Now, i want to save the product name and next .js file. How this can be achieved?
below is the code to create a product. how to save the product name and pass it to other js file?

```js
describe('Should Login to admin and create a product', function() {

   it('should create a dynamic product ', function(done) {
 
    loginPage.login();
    productPage.createProduct();
    productCreatePage.productDynamicGeneral();
    productCreatePage.productDocumentTemplate();
    productCreatePage.stores();
    //productCreatePage.PopUpMessage(dynamicProductCreate);  
    productCreatePage.configurationWithDefaultProfile(); 
});
              
});
```

Comment: you can use `fs.writeFileSync()` package to write product name to a file inside function `productCreatePage.stores()` and read it back in next .js file.   But you have to make sure the next .js file executed after this .jf file via file name of .js file.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using NodeJSs global variables but obviously your tests will need to be executed in the correct order.

**create gbl var.js**

```
describe('Global Var', () => {
    it('will be created', async () => {
        global.gbl_productName = 'New Global Variable Value';
    });
});
```

**Use gbl var**

```
describe('Global Var', () => {
    it('will be used', async () => {
        console.log(gbl_productName);
    });
});
```